# Showing direction when constructing maps on R

Tags: r, maps

So I want to create a map and have a line that connects the two longitude and latitude points, which I have figured out. But I need help with is showing the direction in which the line is going. So in the example below, I want to show an arrow that is going from Cali to Texas. Another issue is how to draw that line such that it does not go over land. So in the example, the line from Cali to Texas would be drawn from Pacific ocean through panama canal and finally to Texas(basically the line is drawn all in the water area). I'm not sure if this is possible but any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
library(maps)
library(geosphere)


xlim=c(-171.738281, -56.601563)
ylim=c(12.039321, 71.856229)
map("world", col="#f2f2f2", fill=TRUE, bg="white", lwd=0.05, xlim=xlim,  ylim=ylim)

lat_ca=39.164141
lon_ca=-121.640625
lat_tx=29.954935
lon_tx=-98.701172
inter2=gcIntermediate(c(lon_ca, lat_ca), c(lon_tx, lat_tx), n=50,     addStartEnd=TRUE)
lines(inter2, col="red",lwd = 12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, the arrow, try adding an arrow just to the last part of the great circle path, like this:

```
arrows(x0=inter2[51,'lon'], y0=inter2[51,'lat'], x1=inter2[52,'lon'], 
       y1=inter2[52,'lat'], col="red",lwd = 12)
```

I put in 51 and 52 here because they are the last 2 rows of your great circle, but a better solution would be

```
arrows(x0=inter2[nrow(inter2)-1,'lon'], y0=inter2[nrow(inter2)-1,'lat'], 
      x1=inter2[nrow(inter2),'lon'], y1=inter2[nrow(inter2),'lat'], col="red",lwd = 12)
```

Comment: And as far as your second part -- why are you using great circle in the first place if you want to avoid land?  Unclear on how to solve this bit.